# Does a continuous map on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ always have a compactly supported extension to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: analysis

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $f : K \to \mathbb R^p$ a continuous map. Is there always an extension $\tilde f$ of $f$ to $\mathbb R^n$ as a whole such that $\tilde f$ is continuous and compactly supported?

Comment: Wlog $p=1$, in which case this is precisely the _Tietze Extension Theorem_.